# pneumatic solenoid operation?

Tags: airflow, compressed-air, pneumatic

Any idea on how this type of pneumatic solenoid works? I know that NC is normally closed, NO normally open, but not sure how air flows? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's not clear if you are showing the electrical or pneumatic connections.

Comment: pneumatic connection is shown in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When no voltage is applied to the solenoid, air will flow between port 2 'Common' and port 3 'Normally Open,' but not to port 1 'Normally Closed.' When voltage is applied, air will flow between port 2 and port 1, but not to port 3. We could likely assume that the direction of air flow is intended to be from port 2 to ports 1 & 3, but it isn't a guarantee and it may not matter to the valve. Note that in pneumatic and hydraulic circuits, normally closed and normally open have the opposite definition as in electrical circuits. For a valve, closed means *not passing* air/oil, whereas for a relay closed means *passing* electrons.

A more standard diagram for this valve would be #3 in the image below:
[image: Example valve diagrams]

Although it's worth noting that the 'T' designation implies a hydraulic valve, and numeric port designations are more common for pneumatic valves.